# Ripple Gem Not Working in Rails4

Tags: rubygems, rabbitmq, ruby-on-rails-4, riak, gemfile

I am using Rails 4.I am trying to make an application using Riak and RabbitMq,
I tried to use `ripple gem` in my application  but returns some error about dependencies like below:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
  ripple (>= 0) ruby depends on
  activemodel (= 3.0.0.beta) ruby

rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  activemodel (4.0.0)
```

I am using latest version of ripple

Is there any fix to this problem?How can I resolve the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you add a version in the `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'ripple', "1.0.0.beta2"
```